# Problemas al cargar script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un inconveniente estoy llamando a una acción de mi controlador y me carga la información sin problemas pero no me está reconociendo mi jQuery-1.11.1.min.js

Depurando estoy dudando si la forma de como devuelvo el reponse es el correcto o incorrecto, que otra alternativa tengo para devolver el resultado de mi controlador (que me retorna a una vista principal).

1. Script

   ```
   {
        $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("CargarRequerimiento_Datos", "Requerimiento")',
           method: "POST",
           data: { 'tiDocu': TIPO, 'NuReqi': NRO_REQUERIMIENTO },
           success: function (response) {
               //document.write(response);
               $('#divPage').html(response);
           },
           async: true
       });
   ```
2. Error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner el html de la respuesta?

Comment: El error pone que no se puede leer la propiedad `length` de una variable indefinida. El código compartido  no contiene ninguna referencia a `length` por lo que no es el causante del problema. En la consola del navegador, junto al error aparece un enlace  al código y línea donde ocurre el error. Revisa (y comparte) ese código.